# Nav bar in blogger

Tags: html, css, blogger

Im trying to create a custom menu bar in my blog but the dropdown menu doesnt come out right and i can't change hover background and also i would like to learn how to switch active class in the menu. I've added the menu using custom HTML/JS script plugin and the code is here. To understand what i mean you can check my blog here, www.tamilegnr.blogspot.in.

```html
<center><div style="max-width:1280px;"><ul>
  <li><a class="active" style="font-size:18px;" href="https://tamilegnr.blogspot.in">Home</a></li>
<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropbtn" style="font-size:18px;" href="https://tamilegnr.blogspot.in/2015/07">Posts</a>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="https://tamilegnr.blogspot.in/search/label/Books">Books</a>
<a href="https://tamilegnr.blogspot.in/search/label/Notes">Notes</a>
<a href="https://tamilegnr.blogspot.in/search/label/Projects">Projects</a>
<a href="https://tamilegnr.blogspot.in/search/label/Softwares">Softwares</a>
</div>
</li>
  <li><a style="font-size:18px;" href="http://tamilengineers.blogspot.in/p/blog-page_20.html">Downloads</a></li>
  <li><a style="font-size:18px;" href="http://tamilengineers.blogspot.in/p/anime-seven-deadly-sins-nanatsu-no.html">Anime</a></li>
</ul>

<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
li.dropdown {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    min-width: 160px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #111;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
.dropbtn {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #111;
}
</style>
</div></center>
```

I've tried changing hover background and everything but it doesnt change so maybe it is only editable on whole template, im not too sure. And dropdown doesnt work here but when tested separately it works fine. So i'd like to know the reason and how to rectify it. Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `class="active"` inline css in the tag that you want to show as active.

Comment: Well that only keeps one item active always viz., Home, but what i'm looking for is a menu bar where the active class changes automatically when i open different page, for examole when i open "Downloads" it should be highlighted and when i go to home then "Home" should be highlighted

Comment: You would have separate html files for Home and Downloads ?
In home.html ->  mark home as active
In downloads.html -> mark downloads as active

Comment: In blogger menu bar is a gadget that is constant in all pages, so we cannot do as you mentioned